# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow Call Http Service Get User Type Data

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I'm having an issue in retrieving the User information in a list field.

I'm calling an web service like:  `https://mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/Items?$filter=Product eq 'Bananas' and Level eq 'Two'`

This filters my search to just one result, and when I try to log in WF history fields like title, product etc. , with `d/results(0)/Title` for example, everything works fine.

There is one field that is an user type field, and I need to retrieve that user filed info such as Id, Name, Email, etc.

Could you advise on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to $expand the user field in the query like this:

```
https://mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/Items?$filter=Product eq 'Bananas' and Level eq 'Two'&$expand=MyUserField&$select=MyUserField/ID,MyUserField/Name,MyUserField/EMail,Product,Level
```

If this is a multi person field you'll need to retrieve them like `d/results(0)/MyUserField/results(0)/Name`

Some more examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx